# How can I readfile txt and input information to Array Data?

Tags: java

I have a question about auto input data from txt file into array. I have this file txt below and I want to take input 2 array like Doctor and Pet.
Doctor: name and specializaion
private ArrayList arrDoctor = new ArrayList<>();
Pet: name, type, size, weight, age,doctor.
private ArrayList arrPet = new ArrayList<>();

This is my file.txt.

```
doctors
name joao
specialisation cat
name maria
specialisation dog
pets
name lara
type cat
size small
weight 4.0
age 5
doctor joao
name biro
type dog
size large
weight 15.0
age 12
doctor maria
name benny
type cat
size large
weight 7.0
age 10
doctor none
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to read file for example like this:

```
try {
      File file = new File("PATH/TO/FILE/filename.txt");
      Scanner myReader = new Scanner(file);
      while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = myReader.nextLine(); // this will be your single line in a file
        someLogicHere(line);
      }
      myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // handle file not found
    }
```

After a line is parsed into program you would need some logic to determine if this is a doctor or a pet and create objects inside code.

This logic would look soomething like this :

```
String firstLine = "name joao";
String secondLine = "specialisation cat";
String name = firstLine.replace("name ", ""); // get rid of this name prefix
String specialisation = secondLine.replace("specialisation ", ""); // get rid of this specialisation prefix
Doctor doctor = new Doctor(name, specialisation);
```

I would strongly suggest to split doctors and pets into different files to make it easier for you. Addicionally what would make it even easier for you to have a doctor and pet writen one line per each not to have to parse to or more lines to create single object.
Ex `name joao specialisation cat`